# Using an Express app with MongoDB to execute a 'create' function on clients browser instead of the server

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, mongoose, ejs

I have created an internet speed test app using client speed, location, and ISP. Problem is that when this code is executed it pulls the speed, ISP and location of where the data centre is wherever it is deployed(in my example an AWS server in Virginia via Heroku). My thought is that I need this code to execute on the client's browser side instead of on the server. Is this possible using Express, Mongoose, and EJS?

Relevant code posted below. This is from my controller. I didn't include the rest because it's just logic for something separate/render code.

```
function index(req, res, next) {

  let speedtest = new FastSpeedtest({
    token: hidden, // required
    verbose: false, // default: false
    timeout: 10000, // default: 5000
    https: true, // default: true
    urlCount: 5, // default: 5
    bufferSize: 8, // default: 8
    unit: FastSpeedtest.UNITS.Mbps, // default: Bps
    proxy: "http://optional:auth@my-proxy:123", // default: undefined
  });

  speedtest.getSpeed().then((s) => {
      fetch(ipApiToken).then(function (response) {
        response.json().then((jsonData) => {
          res.render("testSpeed", { s, jsonData });
        });
      });
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e.message);
    });
}

async function create(req, res, next) {

    let userIsp = req.body.isp
    let userSpeed = req.body.speed
    let userLocation = req.body.location

    let newSpeedTest = await importSpeed.speedModel.create({speed: Math.round(userSpeed),location: userLocation, isp: '', isp_id: ''});
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible since you send the request from the server.

If you want to obtain data such as ping / download speed etc. from a computer, you have to send the request from this very computer.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Just to clarify, is there any way to re-write 'speedtest.getSpeed()' on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

The API I'm pulling JSON info from (ipapi) can pull data using an IP address. Luckily I found that Express has a built-in feature in 'req' for pulling the client's IP address. I still have the issue of getting accurate speed tests but this might help other people in the future.

```
var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
```

This pulls the client IP address in a controller function.

I just changed it to:

```
  speedtest.getSpeed().then((s) => {
  fetch('https://ipapi.co/' + ip + '/json/?key=' + ipApiToken).then(function (response) {
    response.json().then((jsonData) => {
      res.render("testSpeed", { s, jsonData });
    });
  });
})
```

The full code with these changes:

```
function index(req, res, next) {

  var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;

  let speedtest = new FastSpeedtest({
    token: 'YXNkZmFzZGxmbnNkYWZoYXNkZmhrYWxm', // required
    verbose: false, // default: false
    timeout: 10000, // default: 5000
    https: true, // default: true
    urlCount: 5, // default: 5
    bufferSize: 8, // default: 8
    unit: FastSpeedtest.UNITS.Mbps, // default: Bps
    proxy: "http://optional:auth@my-proxy:123", // default: undefined
  });

  speedtest.getSpeed().then((s) => {
      fetch('https://ipapi.co/' + ip + '/json/?key=' + ipApiToken).then(function (response) {
        response.json().then((jsonData) => {
          res.render("testSpeed", { s, jsonData });
        });
      });
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e.message);
    });
}
```